# Displayport Dell d6000 No video from Dell xps 13 via usb C

Tags: display, dell

**answer at bottom**

I have a dell xps 9360 13" connected to a dell d6000.  Connecting to the display port results in a blank monitor, when I connect via hdmi it displays, as on the d6000 there is only one hdmi and 2 display ports this isn't ideal.

When I connect and disconnect a monitor from the display port, both the hdmi connect monitor and the laptop screen turn on and off, so something is being registered.

Any ideas on how I remedy this?

**UPDATE**

Re justin's response

I believe I had already installed the latest display link drivers.  When I decided to retry this process as per the answer, i get this response which I don't beleieve I got before.

Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 4.4.24  100%
DisplayLink Linux Software 4.4.24 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Installing EVDI kernel module to kernel tree
EVDI kernel module built successfully
Installing x64-ubuntu-1604/DisplayLinkManager
Installing libraries
Installing firmware packages
Installing licence file
Adding udev rule for DisplayLink DL-3xxx/5xxx devices

Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of dlm.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Job for dlm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

systemctl status dlm.service
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of dlm.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● dlm.service - DisplayLink Manager Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dlm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-01-30 10:12:11 CET; 564ms ago
  Process: 16175 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c modprobe evdi || (dkms install evdi/4.4.24 && modprobe evdi) (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

**second update**

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling,

but the dlm.service is still struggling.

-- Unit dlm.service has begun starting up.
Jan 30 20:46:26 sico-XPS-13-9360 sh[17515]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Required key not available

**Jan 30 20:46:26 sico-XPS-13-9360 kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key**

Jan 30 20:46:26 sico-XPS-13-9360 sh[17515]: Module evdi/4.4.24 already installed on kernel 4.15.0-44-generic/x86_64

**Jan 30 20:46:26 sico-XPS-13-9360 sh[17515]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'evdi': Required key not available**

Jan 30 20:46:26 sico-XPS-13-9360 systemd[1]: dlm.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1

Jan 30 20:46:26 sico-XPS-13-9360 systemd[1]: dlm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Jan 30 20:46:26 sico-XPS-13-9360 systemd[1]: Failed to start DisplayLink Manager Service.

I'm reading that this error Jan 30 20:46:26 sico-XPS-13-9360 kernel: PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key

might be related to secure boot being on (i dual boot with elementary and windows 10) or an nvidia driver issue.

**Answer**

**Install driver as indicated in Justin's answer and disable secure boot to make sure dlm.service can function as expected**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dell docking stations use displaylink chips to emulate additional displays.  I have seen this issue with the display ports and installing the [latest display manager software](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu) for display link seems to remedy it.

### **UPDATE:**

I uninstalled my display manager software and rebooted and tried a clean install with the following as the result:  [image: displaymanagerinstall]

My guess is that it isn't installing correctly and that maybe why your dock is failing to work.

As for other docks, I have used the D3100, D6000, and will so be testing with a TB16 dock.  I have the XPS 15 9570, which is more power hungry.  I don't think you will find one that just works.  From my searching around, most of the use the DisplayLink chipset which will need the DisplayManager software to work.

### For future viewers:

I am currently using the TB16 and it is by far the best dock out of the others I have tried. It is the first dock I can actually hot swap with and haven't had a single issue with it in the two weeks of use.

Also, The D3100 connects via USB and I found I can't use my integrated camera because it uses all the USB bandwidth for screen replication.

Comment: Hi Justin thanks for the response, 

I've updated my question with info related to your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Justin.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling I think it may be a secure boot or nvidia issue

Comment: Ok looks like it was a secure boot issue.  I've disabled that, and now everything is working fine.  Thanks very much again